APK Compatibility Issue on Other Devices - Works Only on My Phone

Description:
I have created and signed an APK using Termux, and it runs perfectly on my Xiaomi Note 11 Pro with Android 13. However, when I try to install it on other devices, I receive an "app not compatible" error. I have verified the APK is signed and have tried multiple methods to troubleshoot, but the issue persists.
Steps to Reproduce:

Create the APK using msfvenom payload creation tool.
Sign the APK using Termux with the following steps:
keytool -genkey -v -keystore /data/data/com.termux/files/home/my-release-key.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias new-key-alias
apksigner sign --ks /data/data/com.termux/files/home/my-release-key.jks --ks-key-alias new-key-alias --ks-pass pass:your_keystore_password --key-pass pass:your_key_password --v1-signing-enabled true --v2-signing-enabled true --v3-signing-enabled true --out ./as2-signed.apk ./as2-rebuilt.apk


Try to install the signed APK on another device with Android 13 or another version.

Expected Behavior:
The APK should install and run on any compatible Android device.
Actual Behavior:
The APK installs and runs only on my Xiaomi Note 11 Pro but fails with a compatibility error on other devices.
APK Details:

Package Name: nous.client
Permissions:
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="nous.client" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <application
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:persistent="true" >
        <activity
            android:name="nous.client.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".RealService" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" />
        <service android:name=".RestartService" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" />
        <receiver android:name=".AlarmRecever"/>
        <receiver
            android:name=".RebootRecever"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:process=":remote">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>



Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

Verified APK signing using apksigner verify --verbose as2.apk.
Checked the APK with aapt dump badging ./as2-signed.apk but received "assets could not be loaded" error.
Attempted multiple signing methods and re-checked compatibility settings.


**Device Details:**
- **Device 1 (Works):**
  - Model: Xiaomi Note 11 Pro
  - Android Version: 13 TP1A.220624.014

- **Device 2 (Fails):**
  - Model: Redmi 12c
  - Android Version: 14UP1A.231005.007

**Questions:**
1. Are there any specific compatibility settings or configurations I might be missing?
2. Could the issue be related to specific permissions or features declared in the manifest?
3. Is there a better way to sign the APK to ensure broader compatibility?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!


I recommend that you edit your question and provide the exact and complete error message that you are receiving.

Please adb jnstall to install your APK on the phone where it fails then copy the output with the error message and include it in your question.

add   android:exported="true"    in mainactivity
